# Request focus from an edittext to another with a different inputType

Tags: android, focus

I have to different EditText like these :

[image]

- EditText1 has the inputType "textCapWords"
- EditText2 has the inputType "number"

When I launch my activity, I instantly request focus on the EditText1. The only way to do so that is working is to add this on the onCreate :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
EDITTEXT1.requestFocus();
```

When the user clicks on "Return" on his soft Keyboard, I want the EDITTEXT2 to obtain focus. So I added this :

```
EDITTEXT1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == 66) { // CODE FOR RETURN
            EDITTEXT2.requestFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

But when I do so, nothing happens. All my EditText are set FocusableInTouchMode and Focusable :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EDITTEXT1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="My First EditText"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="12dip" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EDITTEXT2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="My Second EditText"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="12dip" >
</EditText>
```

Do you have any idea on how I could focus the EDITTEXT2 after pressing OK on EDITTEXT1 ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer. I finally found the easiest way to answer my own question :

Add :

android:nextFocusRight="@+id/EDITTEXT2"

To the properties of EDITTEXT1.

Nothing else is needed in order to go to the EDITTEXT2 after clicking "Enter" on EDITTEXT1.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your own EditText which extended from EditText firstly, then override the mothod `dispatchKeyEventPreIme` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {  
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {  
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {  
            return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);  
        } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {  
            hideInputMethod();
            //change your focus at here
            return true;  
        }  
    }  
    return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);  
}

protected void hideInputMethod() {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext()  
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
    if (null != imm) {  
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);  
    }  
}
```

By the way, it not a good way to code like that `if (keyCode == 66) { // CODE FOR RETURN`, and also 66 is not the value of back, it's key enter.

```
public static final int KEYCODE_ENTER           = 66;
```

you'd better write `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` or `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` instead.

I wish this could help you.